# Docker image silently fails to start

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The following docker image successfully builds but will just not run - without any (visible) error:

```
FROM alpine:3

RUN apk --no-cache add transmission-cli transmission-daemon \
    && mkdir -p /transmission/config \
    && chmod -R 777 /transmission 

RUN apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash
RUN wget -P ./transmission/ https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin

ENV TRACKER_URL="http://104.219.73.18:6969/announce"
RUN echo tracker url is: ${TRACKER_URL}
RUN transmission-create -t ${TRACKER_URL} -o ./transmission/testfile.torrent /transmission/100MB.bin

CMD transmission-daemon -c ./transmission --config-dir ./transmission/
```

The `logs` show nothing for me. What's strange: If I build the image, run a shell inside it and execute the `CMD`, everything runs just fine. I've already tried wrapping the `CMD` in a bash script and executed that (because why not), but with the same result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `tranmission-daemon` yourself on the command line, you'll see that it puts itself into the background. From Docker's perspective, your container just exited!

You need to add the `-f` (`--foreground`) option to your `tranmission-daemon` command line:

```
CMD transmission-daemon -f -c ./transmission --config-dir ./transmission/
```

Comment: thanks for the help, if I run without `-f`, it stays in the foreground for me, and adding `-f` changes nothing? You can reproduce by building the image and running both variants inside the container.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Are you saying, "I tried this and I am still experiencing the same problem", or are you asking "Does `-f` change anything?", or something else? If I make this one change in your Dockerfile it runs correctly for me.

Comment: For magical reasons, it did the trick for me now. this morning, adding -f somehow didn't do anything - probably I messed something up. thanks a lot !